# import文を１行で記述したい

Tags: python, python3

次のように、PythonのPillowパッケージを他のパッケージと区別できるよう、
接頭辞pilを付けて利用したいのですが、いろいろ試したところimport文を２行書かなければ実現できませんでした。１行でimportできないでしょうか？

```
import PIL as pil
from PIL import ImageFont

func = pil.ImageFont.truetype
```

例えば、以下のように接頭辞なしならできるようです。ImageFontに接頭辞pilを付けたいです。

```
import PIL.ImageFont as ImageFont
func = ImageFont.truetype
```

なお、PILは、

```
pip3 install pillow
```

でインストールしました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> １行でimportできないでしょうか？

```
import PIL as pil; from PIL import ImageFont
```

こちらの方がスマートですね

```
import PIL as pil, PIL.ImageFont
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。実現できました。ちなみに自動フォーマット(auto pep8?)すると、複数行でのimpotにリファクタリングされました。そういうものだったのですね。勉強になります。